# Unable to debug OnPagePublishOrUnPublishPost event of Tridion Event System

Tags: 2011, event-system

I have subscribed to an event as below in the Tridion Event system and when I try to debug the code the break point is not getting hit.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishOrUnPublishPost, EventPhases.Initiated);
```

I have tried subscribing to the following event as well but this too not working.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPost, EventPhases.Processed);
```

When I tried the Save event of page that is working correctly. The Following code is working correctly.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(OnPageSavePost, EventPhases.Processed);
```

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of publishing Events, I noticed that some areas are hosted by the TcmPublisher.exe process and other ones by the TcmServiceHost.exe process. I would attach both processes to be sure my code will stop in the break point.

Also make sure your local dll/pdb and deployed dll/pdb files are for the same code version.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried attaching to the TcmPublisher.exe process? You need to attach to this process for publish events (whereas Save is a GUI event, so uses a different process, which depends a bit on what version of Tridion you are using).

Comment: Hey I tried By just adding TcmPublisher.exe, But It didn't worked for me Tridion2011  SP1. But When when I attached both TcmServiceHost.exe and TcmPublisher.exe , It worked for me.